# JPARepository, name method to return field with "text" included

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot 2 and the JPARepository, i need to return the rows that include in a field a word.

Example, i want to return all the rows where in A field there is the word "SearchMe".
What method i have to use?

(For now the word is always in the start of the string, but will be better if search in all the positions.

```
    findByAStartsWith (String search)
    findByAStartingWith (String search)
    findByAisStartingWith (String search)
    findByAContaining (String search)
```

and what difference is there?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Actually i didnt try and i cant try ATM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `%` in JPQL Query.

```
@Query("Select a from TableName a where a.A like %:search%").
```

or From Spring Data proxies like

```
findByAContaining(String search);
```

For Reference - https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
List<Entity> findByALikeIgnoreCase(String searchString);
```

Because you will not need to prepend and append `%`, Additionally it is case-insensitive.